# Matlab File does not run properly

Tags: matlab, runtime-error, nan, delete-row

I don't understand what the errors mean... I was trying to have my code read my text file starting at line 20, and from there, remove any NaN that is found... I'm not sure if I'm taking the right approach or not...

```
fid = fopen('RS1102G1.txt');
Rows = textscan(fid, '%s', 'delimiter', '\n');
fclose(fid);

Columns= cellfun(@(x)textscan(x,'%f','delimiter','\t','CollectOutput',1,'treatAsEmpty',{'VOID'}), Rows{1,1}(19:end, :));

fid(any(isnan(fid),2),:)=[]
```

My new errors are:

Error using textscan
First input can not be empty.

Error in @(x)textscan(x,'%f','delimiter','\t','CollectOutput',1)

Error in SecondScript (line 6)
Columns= cellfun(@(x) textscan(x,'%f','delimiter','\t','CollectOutput',1),
Rows{1,1}(19:end, :));

any suggestions to help me solve this issue would be great, I'm new to matlab, so everything is a learning process.

Comment: check fid, if it's '-1' then opening the file failed. Maybe you have to change working directory fist.

Comment: I checked fid, it equals 3

Comment: That's strange. If you can you should test it on another computer. It should work. Is the problem still existing?

Comment: Okay, I tried it on another computer and the same thing happens, I do however, have new errors which I updated above...

Comment: Okay, I fixed that problem.. it looks referring to the wrong line, but I wanted to check to make sure it was working and actually did remove NaN, Should I use find?